# Bottom margin and its result

Tags: css

[image]

```
.n-drop-cap::first-letter {
    font-size: 105px;
      font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    float: left; 
    margin: 30px 20px 10px 10px;    
}
```

Could you tell me why bottom margin doesn't organize the gap in this case? The address: https://galina.xyz/makiyazh/oshibki-pri-makiyazhe/

[image]

Comment: because the text is too big, it goes out of `<p>`. And there isn't any problem with it right? the letter still works as drop cap perfectly.

Comment: use `line-height`

Comment: Aman Sharma, could you write a code. Becease I can't cope with it.

Comment: @Michael you need to create a snippet what you tried, after that i edit on that

Answer (score 0):

Adding that big margin isn't the best practice and makes it so complicated to scale. First, you have to set a proper *line-height* to make the letter fit in its "content" area,
this is called [Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model), There is content, padding, border, and margin. In order to keep everything organized, we make our content fits inside the content area. we do that with text by sitting *line-height* property. So it should be something like that

```
.n-drop-cap::first-letter {
line-height: 79px;
box-sizing: content-box;
font-size: 95px;
font-weight: bold;
color: red;
float: left;
/* margin-top: 25px; */
/* margin-left: 10px; */
/* margin-right: 10px; */
/* margin-bottom: 62px; */
height: auto;
width: auto;
 }
```

And that is done without adding any margin, as margin makes it so complicated as you go further in your project

[Figure for Box model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAfIG.png)